# session.invalidate() threw null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web

when I invalidate http session it threw an null pointer exception something like below :

Dec 14, 2012 9:49:52 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession expire
SEVERE: Session event listener threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

suggest.

Comment: how are you obtaining session object

Comment: HttpSession session = request.getSession();

Comment: @duffymo [getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()) never returns `null`...

Comment: @duffymo unless `request` request is not `HttpServletRequest`, @Mitul what type is the `request` variable?

Comment: Show the full stack trace of the exception. It seems it's not the session which is null, but some object used by a HttpSessionListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some breakpoints in your code and use your favorite IDE in DEBUG mode to confirm if this 'session' reference variable is pointing to a null object.

Then, just check the documentation to clarify all the details surrounding the getSession() method (it might give you some ideas): http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29

Answer (score -1):

**I think your problem will solved using  this please try it. By Gourav Gavate**
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String op = request.getParameter("operation");
    System.out.println("operation valuse is ->"+op);
    LoginService service = null;
    ResultSet rs= null;
    HttpSession session=null;
    if (op.equals("Login")){
    //System.out.println("1");
    String un=request.getParameter("username");
    String psd=request.getParameter("password");
    try {
        rs = service.searchByUsernameandPassword(un, psd);
        //System.out.println("2");

         while (rs.next()) {
                //System.out.print(rp.getInt(1));
                //System.out.print("\t"+rs.getString(2));
            // System.out.println("in while");
             if(un.equals(rs.getString(3))&& psd.equals(rs.getString(4)))
             {
            //   System.out.println("in if");
             session=request.getSession(true);
             String name = rs.getString(1)+""+rs.getString(2);
             session.setAttribute("name",name);  
          //   System.out.println("set into session");
              response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Registration/Registration.jsp");
             }else{

                    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Registration/Login.jsp");

             }
         }

    } catch (Exception e4) {
        System.out.println(e4);
    }

}   else    if (op.equals("Logout")){
    /*System.out.println("Into logout");
     if(session!=null){  

         System.out.println("Into logout if");    
            session.removeAttribute("name");
            session.invalidate();  
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Registration/Login.jsp");
     }else{
         System.out.println("Into logout else");
         //   session.removeAttribute("name");
              session.invalidate();  
              response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Registration/Login.jsp");
     }
    */
    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(); 
    //session.removeAttribute("name");
    session1.invalidate();
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 
    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Registration/Login.jsp");

}

}
```